# encoding multidimensional array in PHP 7.0 doesn't work (json_encode)

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo, encoding

I have a problem with getting JSON data from mysql phpmyadmin(Version 4.0) table, I have tried PDO and mysql_connect.

My idea: mysql--> PHP--> echo json

The connection to my server works and the SQL statement works perfectly. I have tested it. But the "json_encode"(and some others) of the JSON itself is not possible. The json array is not builted.

Are there settings in PhpMyAdmin which I have to pay attention to?

**PDO:**

```
      $query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT p.*, count(r.rate) AS rates, avg(r.rate) AS average from plugins p left join rate r on p.title = r.title group by p.title');
        $query->execute();
        $row = $query->fetchAll();
        // send the data encoded as JSON
        $json = json_encode($row, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
echo $json;
       print_r($row);
        exit;
```

Result is:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 153 [0] => 153 [title] =>
```

Where am I going wrong? I **updated my server to PHP 7.0** and now the code doesn't work. Before the update all is working perfectly and there was a long json array(how it should be)

How it should be

```
{{"id":"1","title":"ExmapleTitle"....},{"id":"2","title":"ExmapleTitle2"....}...}
```

Comment: Why do you use both mysqli and pdo? Choose one ;-)

Comment: Fetching what? What are the expected results and current results?

Comment: In php7 json_encode only works with utf8, do you have anything in the response that is not? Otherwise, will make it fail

Comment: Which part of the code isn't working? Is `$json_array` and/or `$data` empty? Are you sure your query is correct and is being properly executed?

Comment: PDO and mysqli scripts are in different files of my web page (I have tested a lot of possibilities). I want to convert my MYSQL phpmyadmin databse to utf8 json. I think there is a problem with making such a json array. The script do nothing. No errors or others

Comment: @ClaudioPinoto If I echo the array, the word "Array" is echoed without the utf8 encoding. No real echo. The json_encoding echo do nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must call execute()

```
    <?php

    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=xxxxx;dbname=xxxxx', 'xxxxxx', 'xxxxxx');

    $statement=$pdo->prepare("SELECT p.*, count(r.rate) AS rates, avg(r.rate) AS average from plugins p left join rate r on p.title = r.title group by p.title");

    $statement->execute(); // <<< --- You are missing this
    $data = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($data); //Echo: data ... voila
```

Comment: Thank you. I correct it. But i have got a multidimensional array and the encodeing doesn't work: PHP prints out with print_r.... Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 153 [0] => 153 [title] => 111 Ink Brushes [1] => 111 Ink Brushes [link] => https://myphotoshopbrushes.com/brushes/id/3516/ [2] => https://myphotoshopbrushes.com/brushes/id/3516/ [data] => Ink111.abr [3] => Ink111.abr [text]

Comment: I don't get why you say the encoding does not work. Are you saying that you want the JSON formatted in a particular way?

Comment: If you want the JSON formatted a particular way, then loop through the data and format it how you want. Perhaps you should add a sample output how you want the JSON to look.

Comment: Depends on how you want the output formatted.  If you provide the full print_r output and an example of what you are trying to achieve, I can help you get there.  As it stands, there isn't enough information to provide a thorough answer.

Comment: @CSSMaster it looks like you're missing the `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` argument for the `fetchAll()` method in your code. Add that, and the JSON should be what you're looking for.